# RewriteRule, GET parameters and Relative Path

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, path

I need an explanation about a rewrite rule in htaccess and relative path ...

In my project, I have two files :

```
 - index.php
 - photos.php
```

In my htaccess file, I have :

```
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
RewriteRule ^photos/([0-9]+)$ photos.php?&id=$1
```

I access my `photos.php` file with this address:

```
http://www.example.com/photos/15
```

In my `photos.php` file, if I create the link `<a href="home"`, I get a 404 error. Because it tries to access the URL: `http://www.example.com/photos/index.php`

Can someone explain to me what's my error?

Comment: This is an entirely client-side / browser issue, rather than .htaccess/RewriteRule. The _browser_ resolves any relative path to be relative to the current URL-path (unless you have a `base` element). As far as the _browser_ is concerned, you are now in a "directory" called "photos", so any relative client-side path is going to be relative to the "photos" subdirectory. It doesn't matter that "photos" doesn't exist as a physical directory - the browser/user doesn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using a relative URL `href="home"` and your current URL is: `/photos/15` that's why browser resolves this relative URL to `/photos/home` which obviously will cause a 404.

You have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
**Otherwise** You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.